Illustrator elements acting grouped
There is no mask, no compound path, no lock in the layers panel, no reason for the elements to act like they are grouped. I know they were never grouped because I built the file. There is a bounding line around the elements that can be deleted with the direct selection tool. This allows for selection but not individual selection unless I use the direct selection tool. The direct selection tool only selects a signgle element. This has been happening for some time and I cannot release it.

image of a expanded layers palette would make it possible to gauge whats going on.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There could be other things going on, such as an opacity mask, which will be hidden in the appearance panel. It's really hard to answer questions like this when we have no access to your file. Only guesses are possible.  Please consider showing us some screen shots of the layers expanded, etc.

Sounds like a clipping mask or "draw inside" was used... do need to see the layers panel to know more.
